# Set default baud rate on /dev/ttyAMA0 and keep after reboot

Tags: raspbian, gpio, serial, uart, gps

I have a [ITead Studio GPS](http://raspberrypiaustralia.com.au/collections/crusts-add-ons/products/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on) attached to my RasPi Model B 2.0's UART serial port and it's specifications require baud rate to be set at `38400`.

I am using `gpsd` on Raspbian, which attempts to use baud rates 4800, 9600, 19200 then after a while it attempts 38400 and eventually starts working after a lot of timeouts.

Each time I reboot, I need to manually run the following:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 38400
```

After reboot, the baud rate returns to the default `115200`.

Is it possible to set the default baud rate to `38400`, so that I do not have to run the above command each time I reboot?

My `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

My `/etc/iniitab`:

```
# /sbin/getty invocations for the runlevels.
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1 
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6

#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Comment: The /dev/ttyAMA0 is a UART connected to a pair of gpio pins.  As far as I'm aware there in no link between /dev/ttyAMA0 and any serial port presented by the USB hardware (normally something like /dev/ttyUSB0).  Are you using two serial devices?

Answer (score 4):

well it's an old issue, but maybe for others who are searching for a solution, just edit the crontab like follows :

```
@reboot sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 38400
```

works also with other commands :)