# Set permission for /dev/ttyAMA0 on boot

Tags: raspbian, permissions

For some reason in Raspbian (Jessie) `/dev/ttyAMA0` always boots with the following permissions:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 204, 64 Jun  1 21:10 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I need group `tty` to have read access, so emulating [this solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37848/9288) I tried adding a root crontab job:

```
@reboot chmod 660 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Which appears to either have no effect or is reverted immediately.  Grateful for any tips.

Comment: Doesn't the above show that tty has write access?

Comment: @joan Sorry I mean _read_ access!

Answer (score 8):

The following will ensure read access, but changes group from `tty` to `dialout`.

```
sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

And on reboot we have:

```
# ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Jun  2 11:29 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I've been advised that to do this you should also consider stopping any kernel console logging going out the serial port, which can be achieved by removing `console=serial0,115200` from file `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Any comment on any unintended implications of this method would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that if you remove kernel console logging going to the serial port, the device permissions are what we want (crw-rw----, group dialout) - you don't need the `systemctl mask` command. This would make sense as there's a need to protect kernel logs. The kernel console logging can also be disabled via `raspi-config` - namely in the interfacing options (this does exactly the same as removing the console=... section from /boot/cmdline.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could always add:

```
chmod 660 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

to the /etc/rc.local file. As rc.local is executed with root privileges it should work.

Comment: Yeah already tried that, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the permissions are wrong.

Until they are corrected use the following in the root crontab.

`@reboot (sleep 30; chmod 660 /dev/ttyAMA0)&`

Comment: I suspect this might work, but it does feel a bit hacky! Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

For my RPi 3 Model B, I used geotheory's solution (sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service) for /dev/ttyS0 and it was the cure to my problem of flaky serial communication. Characters were dropping and the connection was timing out frequently. Now it's solid.